# Gatsby: Puppeteer Causes TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Tags: reactjs, puppeteer, gatsby

I'm trying to generate images for each of my Gatsby posts when I run gatsby build using puppeteer. I have included the following script in my `puppet.js`:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const baseUrl = process.argv[2] || 'http://localhost:8000/'
const takeScreenshot = async (slug) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    })
    let url = `${baseUrl}/${slug}/thumbnail`
    let destination = `/static/posts/${slug}-share.png`
    let width = 440
    let height = 220
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    })
    await page.screenshot({
        path: destination,
        clip: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width,
            height,
        },
    })

    await browser.close()
    res.status(200).send("ok");


}


const main = async (file) => {
    const destinationFile = `/static/posts/${file}-share.png`

    await takeScreenshot(file)
    console.log(`Created ${file}`)


}

function generateImage(slug) {

    const file = slug
    main(file)
}

module.exports.generateImage = generateImage
```

I call it in my `gatsby-node.js` like so:

```
var image = require('./src/utils/puppet')
```

And execute it like so:

```
const toolNodes = data.portfolio.nodes;
let slugs = [];
toolNodes.map(toolNode => slugs.push(toolNode.slug));  

console.log(slugs)
slugs.forEach(node => {
   image.generateImage(node) 
 })
```

Above, I make an array of `slug` values and run the function `generateImage` for each of them. In theory, this value should be passed to the `puppet.js` file which should then use it to navigate to the correct url, take a screenshot and save the file.

Instead of working, I get this:

```
Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
```

How can I fix this? Currently, I do not see any output of images in my directories.

Additionally, is this way to go about it a bad idea? Should this script be in my gatsby-node.js at all? If not, where do I run this from?

For additional context, [this is my gatsby-node.js file](https://gist.github.com/thedivtagguy/9f04108063ba22025dde7553382c1c45)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with this.

1. During `gatsby build`, the Gatsby development server is not running, so `localhost:8000` is not likely to be serving your website for Puppeteer to crawl
2. The `createPages` function is called earlier in the booting process for `gatsby develop` than the Express server binding, so at the time this code runs in development `localhost:8000` will similarly not be available
3. `takeScreenshot` is async, but you're not waiting for it to finish before calling `resolve` on the Promise being returned by `createPages`, so Gatsby isn't waiting for them to finish

You might consider instead using `onPostBuild` to generate these images if you are able to predetermine the path for any references to them. You would still need to run a server to get the pages to be available to Puppeteer (e.g. with Express), though, and this might get tricky since you haven't finished the build.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your points make sense. How would I go about using `onPostBuild` for this script? Is there any alternate way to change this script to be run only after the server is running, or indeed create a server when the function is called?

Comment: Yeah that's what I suggested (running a server via Express during `onPostBuild`). [Here's an example.](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm limited by my own understanding of this as I don't know how to use Express, or where to define the `onPostBuild` functions. Would you be able to share a minimal example that I could flesh out, based on my context?

Comment: `onPostBuild` works similar to `createPages` (i.e. export a function from `gatsby-node.js`). I'd link to the docs for it, but they really don't have any more information. Express is pretty simple—I linked to a relevant page in the docs, but feel free to start back at the getting started guide to familiarize yourself.